# Error with Windows App Certification Kit

Tags: windows-store-apps, wack

I keep getting the following error when I run the Windows App Certification Kit.

"Task failed to enable HighVersionLie"

I am using VS 2017 Community and it happens on multiple machines.  The only thing I add is the Template Studio templates with a couple pages.

I have reinstalled VS 2017 Community and updated windows.

Comment: Which version of the Windows App Certification Kit and windows OS are you using ? And your app's target version.

Comment: Edit these values in the `Package.appxmanifest` file.
    `<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17134.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />`

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Don’t Fail the HighVersionLie"](http://rwandering.net/2009/04/16/dont-fail-the-highversionlie/):

> ... there is a certification test called the HighVersionLie that tests
>   for just this case.  The test sets the Windows version to an
>   artificially high number to see if the tested software still installs
>   and runs.

My guess would be that there is something in your version of [Template Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio) that causes your app to crash when the test tells (or "lies to") your app, telling it that it is on a higher, as yet unreleased version of Windows.  You might try searching your code for "DeviceFamilyVersion" to see if there is an "if statement" that doesn't allow for higher versions of Windows.  You might also check to make sure you are using the latest version of [Template Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio) templates.  [Version 1.6 of the Windows Template Studio was just released.](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/12/21/windows-template-studio-1-6-released/?utm_campaign=appnl&utm_source=autopilot&utm_medium=email&utm_content=decappnl_wts#EwmtHYEM2BOCRsDr.97)

You might also try [Changing your target versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version) to higher values to see if that gets rid of the error.

Here is a description of the [Windows App Certification Kit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests)