# Error with Windows App Certification Kit (HighVersionLie failure)

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, app-certification-kit

I'm experimenting the following error when I run the Windows App Certification Kit on a brain new C# Universal App: "Task failed to enable HighVersionLie".

- Windows 10 1709 (Build 16299.125)
- Visual Studio Pro 2017 (15.5.4)
- New project C# Universal App (no additional code added to the project)
- Min SDK version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)
- Target SDK version: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)
- Windows App Certification Kit: 10.0.16299.15

If I generate the appxbundle, the certification kit fails with error "Task failed to enable HighVersionLie".

If I copy this appxbundle on another Windows 10 instance with the same certification kit and pass the test again, there is no error (the HighVersionLie passed successfully)

Answer (score 1):

The "HighVersionLie" test checks to see if your app will crash if it is told that it is running on a new, higher version of Windows (a version which has not been released yet).

I'm guessing that the machine you are seeing the problem on has a problem running this test, and it is not the app's problem.

If you run Visual Studio [as Administrator](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-run-programs-administrator-windows-7), and then run the tests, do you still see the problem?

You might also check for a corrupt installation by running [sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) from a command prompt, or [reinstalling Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747780/reinstall-visual-studio-2015)

Finally, you might try [running Event Viewer](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-event-viewer-in-windows-10.html), and checking the "Application" log to see if there are any Errors around the time you ran your certification test.  If you see an error here, Google the description to find out what's wrong.

If you still think it is a problem with the app, you might check out my [HighVersionLie answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978772/error-with-windows-app-certification-kit)